# JQuery the first request blocks the following request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am building up a web application. I have a button on the tab 1. After this button has been clicked, there are some logic processing in the backend. Then I want to navigate to tab 2. In this tab, I can see the update on the processing.

But the problem is, after I click the button, the related function (ajax() function) has been called. But when I call the tab 2, the function is not triggered by the tabselect event or the event is not triggered. For testing, I added an alert function at the beginning of the tab 2 tabselect event.

I used jQuery in frontend and Flask in backend

Following is the button click event

```
    <i>
         /** Start test button request **/
            $('#btn_start_test').click(function() {
                $('#btn_start_test').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('#btn_stop_test').removeAttr('disabled');
                setTestStatus('running');
                var indexes = '';
                var test_option = $('input[@name=test_option]:checked').val();
                if (test_option == 1) { // Test checked testsuites
                    $.each($('input[name="testsuites_group"]:checked'), function(index, value) {
                        indexes += '&index' + index + '=' + $(this).attr('id');
                    });
                }
                var startTest = $.ajax({
                                                    type: 'POST',
                                                    url: '/start_test',
                                                    data: indexes
                                             });
                //startTest.complete(function() {
                //  $('#btn_start_test').removeAttr('disabled');
                //  $('#btn_stop_test').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                //  setTestStatus('idle');
                //});
            });
    </i>
```

Following is another tab select event:

```
            $("#tabs").bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
                if (ui.index == 0) {
                    loadPage();
                }else if (ui.index == 1) {
                    loadStatusTab();
                }
            });
```

Comment: place here you javascript code

Comment: The second event(click the tab) is triggered as soon as the first event (click the button) get the response from the server. I think the problem is on the client side. When the first event is triggered, it occupies the main process and waiting until the response from server return and then gives out the process to the second event. Is there any way that do not wait and block when triggering one event? Thanks.